# Kill Linux processes based on commands present

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, sh

I am learning Linux and need to write a shell script that will kill all processes whenever another command runs on it. I know how to write a script with a variable, but cannot seem to find ways of doing it for a command.

I would imagine that I need to find a way to evaluate if the command is true or not and to use that as the condition for an if statement. But anything I try returns errors.

Linux is the first CS related thing that I am learning and I am absolutely stuck at this step. I tried searching for this but am not quiet sure what to write.

It's the sh shell.

Edit: Whenever a program is executed with a certain command I need the script to terminate it right away.

Comment: This sounds like you plan to use a heavy hammer to try to fix your watch... You should not simply "kill" processes. Usually they can be stopped in a more graceful way. But that obviously depends on the specific processes you want to handle which you did not say.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what other processes you need to kill and what "whenever another command runs on it" means exactly?

Comment: It's for an assignment. I didn't want to post too many specifics since I want to do the work myself, I just can't figure out where to begin.

Comment: "Figure out where to begin" ? I suggest you start by reading the man bash page brings along: `man bash`... The linux man pages are a wealth of information. _Use it!_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can use this construct in a bash conditional:

```
if [ "$(whoami)" -ne "0" ] then;
```

Where the `whoami` is an example for a an existing script. Obviously the same is possible with many other notations, not only the `if` conditional. Take a look at the `test` command, it is very helpful for such things.

For more details take a look at the "man page" bash brings along: `man bash`

The "Linux man pages" offer a wealth of information.

Comment: I am going to read through it now. I found some stuff with the test command where I can see whether or not something is true which is what I need. I'm going to figure out how to apply that to a running command. Thank you.